# PHP Jquery:Convert HTML to JSON from given url and create a tree view of html elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Basically I have a textbox where I'll enter URL and click "OK button", It will show preview of HTML at left side of page; and right side will have a tree view of HTML tags (body, header, div, span, etc.) used in HTML as attached image. Expected JSON result should be as end of this question. I am failing traversing JSON and creating tree. I tried the following:

HTML and JS code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>ABC</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1 class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" title="" /></h1>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" id="url" value="" class="txt-box" />
            <input type="button" value="OK" class="btn-search" />
        </div>
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            <div class="left-wrap" id="preview-sec">

            </div>
            <div class="right-wrap" id="tree-sec">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script><!-- Jquery plugin -->
<script>
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-search').click(function(){
        if ($('#url').val() != '') {
            $.get(
                'http://localhost/test/getHTML.php', {url:$('#url').val()},
                function(response) {
                    $('#preview-sec').html(response);
            },'html');
            $.getJSON('http://localhost/test/results.json', function(json) {    
                traverse(json,0);               
            });
        }
    });
});
function traverse(obj,id){
    if (typeof(obj)=="object") {
        if (id == 0) {
            $('#tree-sec').append('<ul></ul>');
        } else {
            $(id).append('<ul></ul>');
        }
        $.each(obj, function(i,val){
            if (i != 'attributes' && i != 'value') {
                counter += 1;
                var li_populate = "<li id="+i+"-"+counter+">"+i+"</li>"; 
                if (id == 0) {
                    $('#tree-sec ul').append(li_populate);
                } else {
                    $(id).find('ul').append(li_populate);
                }
                traverse(val,"#"+i+"-"+counter);
            }
        })
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    function html_to_obj($html) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        return element_to_obj($dom->documentElement);
    }

    function element_to_obj($element) {
        //print_r($element);
        $obj = array();
        $attr = array();
        $arr = array();
        $name = $element->tagName;
        foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
            $attr[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
            if ($attribute->name == 'id') {
                $name .= '#'.$attribute->value;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($attr)) {
            $arr["attributes"] = $attr;
        }
        if ($element->nodeValue != '') {
            $arr["value"] = $element->nodeValue;
        }

        foreach ($element->childNodes as $subElement) {         
            if ($subElement->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {

            }
            elseif ($subElement->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {

            }
            else {
                $arr["child_nodes"][] = element_to_obj($subElement);
            }
        }
        $obj[$name] = $arr;
        return $obj;
    }
    $json = json_encode(html_to_obj($html));
    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp,$json);
    fclose($fp);
    echo $html;exit();
?>
```

JSON tree output:

[image]

JSON Result:

```
    {
    "html": {
        "attributes": {
            "lang": "en"
        },
        "value": "Test Development Test\r\n            *{\r\n                box-sizing:border-box;\r\n            }\r\n            body {\r\n                margin:0;\r\n                font-family: sans-serif;\r\n                color: #999;\r\n            }\r\n            a, a:visited {\r\n                text-decoration:none;\r\n            }\r\n            .movie-list .movie{\r\n                width:250px;\r\n                float:left;\r\n                margin-right:25px;\r\n            }\r\n            .movie-list .movie img{\r\n                width:100%;\r\n            }\r\n            .movie-list .movie a.title{\r\n                text-decoration:none;\r\n                color:#999;\r\n                font-weight:bold;\r\n                font-size:18px;\r\n                line-height:25px;\r\n            }\r\n            .movie-list .movie .synopsis{\r\n                font-size:14px;\r\n                line-height:20px;\r\n            }\r\n",
        "child_nodes": {
            "head": {
                "child_nodes": {
                    "meta": {
                        "attributes": {
                            "name": "description",
                            "content": "A ast of animated movies"
                        }
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "value": "Test Development Test"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "text/css"
                        },
                        "value": "\r\n            *{\r\n                box-sizing:border-box;\r\n            }\r\n            body {\r\n                margin:0;\r\n                font-family: sans-serif;\r\n                color: #999;\r\n            }\r\n            a, a:visited {\r\n                text-decoration:none;\r\n            }\r\n            .movie-list .movie{\r\n                width:250px;\r\n                float:left;\r\n                margin-right:25px;\r\n            }\r\n            .movie-list .movie img{\r\n                width:100%;\r\n            }\r\n            .movie-list .movie a.title{\r\n                text-decoration:none;\r\n                color:#999;\r\n                font-weight:bold;\r\n                font-size:18px;\r\n                line-height:25px;\r\n            }\r\n            .movie-list .movie .synopsis{\r\n                font-size:14px;\r\n                line-height:20px;\r\n            }\r\n"
                    }
                }
            },
            "body": {
                "child_nodes": {
                    "h1": {
                        "value": "List of animated movies"
                    },
                    "div": {
                        "attributes": {
                            "class": "movie-list"
                        },
                        "child_nodes": {
                            "div#bh_6": {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "class": "movie",
                                    "id": "bh_6",
                                    "data-year": "2014"
                                },
                                "child_nodes": {
                                    "img": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "src": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjI4MTIzODU2NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjE0NDAwMjE@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "a": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "title",
                                            "href": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2245084/"
                                        },
                                        "value": "Big Hero 6"
                                    },
                                    "div": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "synopsis"
                                        },
                                        "value": "The special bond that develops between plus-sized inflatable robot Baymax, and prodigy Hiro Hamada, who team up with a group of friends to form a band of high-tech heroes."
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "div#tlm": {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "class": "movie",
                                    "id": "tlm",
                                    "data-year": "2014"
                                },
                                "child_nodes": {
                                    "img": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "src": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4MDk1ODExN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzIyNjg3MDE@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "a": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "title",
                                            "href": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/"
                                        },
                                        "value": "The Lego Movie"
                                    },
                                    "div": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "synopsis"
                                        },
                                        "value": "An ordinary Lego construction worker, thought to be the prophesied 'Special', is recruited to join a quest to stop an evil tyrant from gluing the Lego universe into eternal stasis."
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "div#httyd": {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "class": "movie",
                                    "id": "httyd",
                                    "data-year": "2010"
                                },
                                "child_nodes": {
                                    "img": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "src": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjA5NDQyMjc2NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjg5ODcyMw@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "a": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "title",
                                            "href": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0892769/"
                                        },
                                        "value": "How to Train Your Dragon"
                                    },
                                    "div": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "synopsis"
                                        },
                                        "value": "A hapless young Viking who aspires to hunt dragons becomes the unlikely friend of a young dragon himself, and learns there may be more to the creatures than he assumed."
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "div#up": {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "class": "movie",
                                    "id": "up",
                                    "data-year": "2009"
                                },
                                "child_nodes": {
                                    "img": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "src": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk3NDE2NzI4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzE1MzEyMTE@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "a": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "title",
                                            "href": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1049413/"
                                        },
                                        "value": "Up"
                                    },
                                    "div": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "synopsis"
                                        },
                                        "value": "By tying thousands of balloons to his home, 78-year-old Carl sets out to fulfill his lifelong dream to see the wilds of South America. Russell, a wilderness explorer 70 years younger, inadvertently becomes a stowaway."
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "div#mi": {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "class": "movie",
                                    "id": "mi",
                                    "data-year": "2001"
                                },
                                "child_nodes": {
                                    "img": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "src": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTY1NTI0ODUyOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTEyNjQ0MDE@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "a": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "title",
                                            "href": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0198781/"
                                        },
                                        "value": "Monsters, Inc."
                                    },
                                    "div": {
                                        "attributes": {
                                            "class": "synopsis"
                                        },
                                        "value": "Monsters generate their city's power by scaring children, but they are terribly afraid themselves of being contaminated by children, so when one enters Monstropolis, top scarer Sulley finds his world disrupted."
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to create an image of the tree or are you trying to create a tree view like the one in the above image?

Comment: Have you tried the PHP Simple HTML Dom library ? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm - Are you trying to get ell the elements within the body ? document ? elements that have a class / id ?

Comment: Can you post the json results? This is what is needed to answer your question. The other parts are incidental.

Comment: I added expected JSON result and improved question a bit for more understanding.

Comment: It is not likely possible to take snapshots of the tree using html/javascript alone. You will need a screen capture tool. If you really need the image generated via javascript then I would recommend svg (gross but a good option), or canvas (which implies a ton more work). Screen capture tools are likely the best option though.

Comment: I don't need a image of tree, its a HTML clickable tree where you can open and close branches like accordion.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, I would like to suggest that there is a beautiful plugin which directly converts JSON to a tree like you want. You can check out the demo here -- http://www.jstree.com/demo/

Answer (score 15):

As per your question, the part where you traverse the returned json object and create the tree is problematic. In your code, the recursive function to traverse the json data had a few minor issues with the generate `ul` code. The structure of the return object made it a bit challenging.

I was able to modify your `html/javascript` code a bit (without changing it too much) to print out the tree. The relevant code below:

CSS:

```
div#tree-sec ul ul{
    margin-left: 25px;
}
div#tree-sec ul li{
    color: #666;
}
div#tree-sec ul a{
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}   
div#tree-sec ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
div#tree-sec ul.collapsible{
    /* Custom parent styles here... */
    /* Such as a folder icon or 'plus' sign */
}
```

HTML & JS:

```
...
...
<div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="left-wrap" id="preview-sec">
        <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="right-wrap" id="tree-sec">
        <ul id="treehtml1"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
....
....
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn-search').click(function(){
            if ($('#url').val() != '') {
                $.get('http://localhost/test/getHTML.php', {url:$('#url').val()}, function(response) {
                    $('#preview-sec').html(response);
                },'html');
                $.getJSON('http://localhost/test/results.json', function(json) {    
                    if(typeof(json) == "object"){
                        traverse(json,'html',1);  
                        makeCollapsible();             
                    }
                });
             }
         });
     });

     function traverse(obj, element, counter){
         for (var i in obj){
             $("#tree"+element+counter).append("<li id='"+i+counter+"'>"+i+"</li>"); // Add element to the tree
             if(obj[i].hasOwnProperty('child_nodes')){
                 $("#"+i+counter).append("<ul id='tree"+i+(counter+1)+"'></ul>"); // If there are children, add a parent ul and pass the name to subsequent recursive calls for each child
                 for(var j in obj[i].child_nodes){
                     traverse(obj[i].child_nodes[j], i, counter + 1); // Recursive call to add child
                 }
             }
          }
      }

      function makeCollapsible(){
          $('ul.parent').each(function(i) {
              var parent_li = $(this).parent('li');
              parent_li.addClass('collapsible'); //Use this selector to style your parent items...

              // Temporarily remove the list from the
              // parent list item, wrap the remaining
              // text in an anchor, then reattach it.
              var sub_ul = $(this).remove();
              parent_li.wrapInner('<a/>').children('a').click(function() {
                 // Toggle the children...
                 sub_ul.toggle();
              });
              parent_li.append(sub_ul);
          });

          // Hide all lists except the outermost.
          $('ul ul').hide();
      }
</script>
....
....
```

This should provide a properly nested `ul` based tree. If creating an image of the tree is a hard requirement, you're best bet is to properly style the generated `ul` code fragment, create an html page with it on the server and then use a server side tool such as [wkhtmltoimage from the wkhtmltopdf package](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) that can be used to render the html document into an image.

Also, one other thing I would like to mention is that instead of loading the retrieved html into a div, I would recommend that you use an `iframe` as then, the retrieved html would not interfere with your current page. In my example above, I have added an `iframe` in the preview `div`. In such a case, you can use php to only output the `json` data and setting the `iframe` to preview the url would be as simple as assigning the url as the `src` attribute of the `iframe`. Like this: `$("#preview").prop("src", $("#url").val())`.

**Edit**: 
Updated code with a fix. Also added a new js function `makeCollapsible()` to retro-actively convert the `ul` into a clickable, collapsible tree structure as per OP's comment. Also added relevant `CSS` styles to style the tree structure. The tree now looks like the below picture for me:

[image: Collapsible, Clickable HTML Tree!]

Answer (score 4):

**Addendum:** This is a long answer, but it addresses specific problems and solutions for the code snippets you provided. I hope you and others will find it worth the time to compare. :)

---

### First, modify your PHP to make cleaner JSON

When parsing the DOM, I recommend setting the element names from the returned object as the associative keys in `$arr['child_nodes']` using `array_merge()` instead of pushing them onto the array as indexed items. To do this, `$arr['child_nodes']` must be defined as an array first. Later, if no items get merged into it, you simply `unset` it before `$arr` gets added to the main object.

This makes the final JSON result simpler to parse by precluding the need to use a nested loop in your javascript when building the tree.

I also recommend inserting conditional checks for `->length` before doing `foreach` loops. Your existing code was throwing "Warning" messages when zero-length elements entered into the loop.

Lastly, you may choose to simplify your logic for handling node types by replacing your current `if, else if, else` statement with a single `if` checking for `$subElement->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE`, which I think is what you're trying to accomplish.

```
<?php
    $url  = $_GET['url'];
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    function html_to_obj($html) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        return element_to_obj($dom->documentElement);
    }
    function element_to_obj($element) {
        $obj = $attr = $arr = array();
        $name = $element->tagName;
        if ($element->attributes->length) {
            foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
                $attr[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
                if ($attribute->name == 'id') {
                    $name .= '#'.$attribute->value;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($attr)) {
            $arr["attributes"] = $attr;
        }
        if ($element->nodeValue != '') {
            $arr["value"] = $element->nodeValue;
        }
        if ($element->childNodes->length) {
            $arr["child_nodes"] = array();
            foreach ($element->childNodes as $subElement) {         
                if ($subElement->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    $arr["child_nodes"] = array_merge($arr["child_nodes"], element_to_obj($subElement));
                }
            }
            if (!count($arr["child_nodes"])) {
                unset($arr["child_nodes"]);
            }
        }
        $obj[$name] = $arr;
        return $obj;
    }
    $json = json_encode(html_to_obj($html));
    $fp   = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $json);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

### Use an iframe

Insert an empty iframe into which you will load your target site. Inserting the markup from another site into yours can (and will likely) cause conflicts with your own code.

```
<div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="left-wrap" id="preview-sec">
        <iframe src=""></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="right-wrap" id="tree-sec">
    </div>
</div>
```

### Simplify the traverse function, reorder async calls

The `traverse` function was suffering from three flaws:

1. The use of a counter to create ids on the fly and then use jQuery to find previously made elements with those ids on which to append list items was a performance drain and confusing to debug.
2. The use of `.find()` resulted in jQuery redundantly entering the recursive call and appending multi-redundant child nodes to the tree.
3. Because it is the callback of a separate asynchronous call, it could execute before the first asynchronous call to `getHTML.php` had finished.

Move the async call to get the JSON into the callback function on the first async call to prevent it from fetching incomplete or old JSON from the server.

You should also use this first callback to set the `iframe` `src` and empty the `#tree-sec` container, so that subsequent actions don't append more than one tree. You could accomplish the same thing by using `.replace()` instead of `.empty()` followed by `.append()`.

To build the tree, I recommend the following simpler approach, which recursively builds the list as a string so that the `.append` method is only called once. For larger trees, this will dramatically improve performance.

You may introduce a counter and dynamically assigned ids to this function if you want to, but I left it out to demonstrate more clearly that they are not needed to build the tree.

I also recommend checking for the existence of child nodes before entering a recursive call. Doing this check allows you to pass in only the child nodes object, which – because of the new JSON resulting from changes made to the PHP script – now contains tag names as the keys instead of indexed keys with the elements as children. If we hadn't simplified the JSON, a second loop would have been required at this point to retrieve each element.

You'll also notice the inclusion of `aria-` attributes and `role` attributes. This sets you up to be fully accessible if you choose.

See: [Using the WAI-ARIA aria-expanded state to mark expandable and collapsible regions (w3.org)](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_the_WAI-ARIA_aria-expanded_state_to_mark_expandable_and_collapsible_regions)

It also provides you with a convenient and semantic way to control CSS and toggle state, which you can see demonstrated in the additional click handler added at the bottom of the script and the CSS example at the bottom of this answer.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function traverse(data, firstTime) {
        if (typeof data === 'object') {  
            var ul = '<ul role="' + (firstTime ? 'tree' : 'group' ) + '">';
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                if (key !== 'attributes' && key !== 'value') {
                    if (val['child_nodes']) {
                        ul += '<li aria-expanded="true" role="tree-item" tabindex="0">';
                        ul += key;
                        ul += traverse(val['child_nodes']);
                        ul += '</li>';
                    } else {
                        ul += '<li role="tree-item" tabindex="0">';
                        ul += key;
                        ul += '</li>';
                    }
                }
            });
            ul += '</ul>';
            return ul;
        }
    }
    $('.btn-search').on('click', function () {
        var url = $('#url').val();
        if (url) {
            $.get(
                'getHTML.php',
                {
                    url: url
                },
                function () {
                    $('#preview-sec iframe').attr('src', url);
                    $('#tree-sec').empty();
                    $.get(
                        'results.json',
                        function (json) {
                            $('#tree-sec').append(traverse(json, true));
                        },
                        'json'
                    );
                },
                'html'
            );
        }
    });
    $('#tree-sec').on('click', 'li[aria-expanded]', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this)
            .attr('aria-expanded', function (i, attr) {
                return !(attr === 'true');
            })
            .children('ul')
            .attr('aria-hidden', function (i, attr) {
                return !(attr === 'true');
            })
            .toggle();
    });
});
```

### Bonus: Use attribute selectors in the CSS

Finally, as mentioned above, the existence of the `aria-` and `role` attributes provides a semantic and convenient way to control the styles.

```
ul[role='tree'] {
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul[role='tree'] li {
    cursor: default;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    font: normal 1em sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
ul[role='tree'] li[aria-expanded] {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #111;
    background: transparent 0 0 no-repeat url('images/arrow-sprite.png');
}
ul[role='tree'] li[aria-expanded="true"] {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
ul[role='tree'] li[aria-expanded="false"] {
    background-position: 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [Library](https://github.com/Jxck/html2json) which is wrote by Jack.

https://github.com/Jxck/html2json

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at XSLT processing. works fine with much less code effort

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="json.xml"?>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <h2>title 2</h2>
    <h3>title 3</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>t1</li>
        <li>t2</li>
        <li>t3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template name="json" match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="*">
{"<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>": "<xsl:if test="count(*)=0"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:if>",
"attributes": {<xsl:for-each select="@*"><xsl:if test="position()>1">,</xsl:if>"<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>": "<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>"</xsl:for-each>},<xsl:call-template name="json"/>}</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct Multi-dimension PHP array for your HTML tags and then give that array as input to the php inbuilt function json_encode($array) and this returns tree structured json output